# Image link area extends outside image

Tags: html, css, web, hyperlink

I am designing a simple HTML website. The problem I have is with my images that I am using as links. I had them positioned where I wanted them but then I noticed that the link area extended to the left of the image. I was using relative positioning and thought that might have something to do with it, but I removed all CSS from my website and it still happens. I have a strictly HTML page and the link area still extends outside the size of the image.

Any idea what's causing this?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Zach's Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen.css" media="screen/projection">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css" media="print">
    <!--[if IE]> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css"
        media="screen, projection"> 
    <![endif]-->




    <div id="header">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <img id="headbanner" class="span-24" src="img/headerbanner.png">

            <a id="headerLogo" href="index.html"><img class="prepend-3" src="img/ZBLogoHeader.png"></a>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>                        
            </ul>
            <ul class="social">
                <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/zachburns12" target="_blank"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/zach.burns1" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.anovelidea12.tumblr.com/" target="_blank"><img src="img/tumblr.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/zach-burns/39/538/335/" target="_blank"><img src="img/linkedin.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.github.com/zburns12" target="_blank"><img src="img/github.png"></a></li>
            </ul>

            <img id="bodyPattern" src="img/body.png">
        </div>
    </div>

</head>

<body>  

    <div id="project1" class="container clearfix">

        <a href="#"><img id="novel" class="prepend-2" src="img/ANovelIdea.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='img/hoverNovel.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/ANovelIdea.jpg'" /></a>

        <a href="#"><img id="barminder" class="prepend-8" src="img/Barminder.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='img/hoverBar.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/Barminder.jpg'" /></a>


    </div>

</body>
<footer>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <img id="footerLogo" src="img/ZBLogoFooter.png">
        <img id="footerBanner" src="img/footerbanner.png">
    </div>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: thats odd.. fiddle some code. never run into that before.

Comment: Impossible to help you without the relevant markup and a specific example...

Comment: There's the HTML. I have the CSS commented out so it's not relevant. I'm using the blueprint CSS grid if that makes any difference

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting a height/width to the 'a' tag? Ideally you should be setting height, width and display:block, so that the 'a' tag has its exact size.
`a{
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}`

Comment: I just added that. It still does it. The odd thing is that the small pictures I'm using for my social media links don't have this problem. And the navigation doesn't either. It's only the logo image and the images with the ID project1

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a href="#" title="logo"><img src="#" alt="logo image"></a>

/* CSS */
a {display: block; width: 50%;}
img {width: 100%;}
```

You set the width of the link then you set the width of the image to 100% of the link width. Then you adjust the width of the link until the image is the size you need. Link won't go past the width of the image this way.

Answer (score 1):

So...I stumbled on this because I was having the same issue.  Then, when I didn't see the answer here, I tried one last-ditch effort.  I set all of my images wrapped in A tags to display: block; in the CSS.  Before that, the A tag was allowing users to click far outside the image to the right where there was just white space caused by the display: block; default.  Try **display: inline-block** because it caused the link to force itself down only to the edges of the image.  Hope that works for you!